# The minimum cardinality of an almost disjoint reaping family

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

The following cardinal arose in the discussion surrounding the question posed [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275633/existence-of-a-diagonal-set-in-certain-set-systems) by Dominic van der Zypen:

Define $\kappa$ to be the minimum cardinality of a family $\mathcal{A}$ of infinite subsets of $\omega$ such that

a) if $A\neq B$ in $\mathcal{A}$ then $A\cap B$ is finite, and

b) for every $D\subseteq\omega$ there is an $A\in \mathcal{A}$ such that $A\subseteq D$ or $A\cap D=\emptyset$.

The answers to the original question established $\aleph_1\leq\kappa\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$, and it was asked whether this cardinal might be equal to one of the standard cardinal characteristics of the continuum.  We will ask a particular manifestation of this question after proving a few facts about $\kappa$.

The first thing we note is that $\kappa$ can be defined using the ``mod finite'' relations $\subseteq^*$ and $=^*$ instead of $\subseteq$ and $=$.

**Claim 1**: 
$\kappa$ is the minimum cardinality of a family $\mathcal{A}$ of infinite subsets of $\omega$ such that

a) if $A\neq B$ in $\mathcal{A}$ then $A\cap B$ is finite, and

b) for every $D\subseteq\omega$ there is an $A\in \mathcal{A}$ such that either $A\subseteq^* D$ or $A\cap D=^*\emptyset$.

Proof: Clearly a family as in the definition of $\kappa$ satisfies the weaker condition of Claim 1.  Given a family $\mathcal{A}$ satisfying (a) and (b) of Claim 1, we build a new family $\mathcal{A}^*$ by splitting each member of $\mathcal{A}$ into countably many disjoint infinite sets.  Clearly $|\mathcal{A}|=|\mathcal{A}^*|$, and $\mathcal{A}^*$ satisfies the requirements of the definition of $\kappa$.$_\square$

A family $\mathcal{A}\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ satisfying (a) is called *almost disjoint*, while a family $\mathcal{A}\subseteq [\omega]^\omega$ satisfying (b) (from Claim 1) is said to be a *reaping family*.  So $\kappa$ is can be defined as the minimum cardinality of an almost disjoint reaping family, and the answers to van der Zypen's original question establish that such things exist.

Recall that $\mathfrak{r}$ is defined to be the minimum cardinality of a reaping family in $[\omega]^\omega$, and $\mathfrak{u}$ is defined to be the minimum cardinality of an ultrafilter base on $\omega$, that is, the minimum cardinality of a family $\mathcal{B}\subseteq[\omega]^\omega$ such that $\{A\subseteq\omega: (\exists B\in\mathcal{B})[B\subseteq A]\}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$.  Note that $\mathfrak{r}\leq\mathfrak{u}$ by an easy argument.

**Claim 2**: $\mathfrak{r}\leq\kappa\leq\mathfrak{u}$.

Proof.  $\mathfrak{r}\leq\kappa$ trivially, as an almost disjoint reaping family is a reaping family.  The proof that $\kappa\leq\mathfrak{u}$ relies on work of Balcar and Vojtas (available [here](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2043088?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)).  Their Corollary 1.7 establishes that whenever $\mathcal{U}$ is a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$, there is a collection $\{A_X:X\in\mathcal{U}\}$ such that

i) $A_X$ is an infinite subset of $X$ for all $X\in\mathcal{U}$, and

ii) if $X\neq Y$ in $\mathcal{U}$, then $A_X\cap A_Y$ is finite.

The collection $\{A_X:X\in\mathcal{U}\}$ is called an *almost disjoint refinement of $\mathcal{U}$*.

Now let $\mathcal{U}$ be a non-principal ultrafilter on $\omega$ with a base $\mathcal{B}$ of cardinality $\mathfrak{u}$, and let $\{A_X:X\in\mathcal{U}\}$ be an almost disjoint refinement of $\mathcal{U}$.

Then $\mathcal{A}:=\{A_X:X\in\mathcal{B}\}$ has the required properties:  given $D\subseteq\omega$ there is a $X\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $X\subseteq D$ (if $D\in\mathcal{U}$) or $X\cap D=\emptyset$ (if $D\notin\mathcal{U}$).  Since $A_X\subseteq X$ we have what we need. $_\square$.

The following observation gives us yet another definition of $\kappa$:

**Claim 3**:  $\kappa$ is the minimum cardinality of a reaping family with an almost disjoint refinement.

Proof:  An almost disjoint reaping family serves as its own almost disjoint refinement, and an almost disjoint refinement of a reaping family is an almost disjoint reaping family of the same cardinality. (Note that the Balcar-Vojtas result quoted above shows us that ultrafilter bases are reaping families with almost disjoint refinements.) $_\square$

Finally, we get to the natural questions raised by the above discussion:

**Questions**:

1) Is $\kappa=\mathfrak{r}$?

2) Is $\kappa=\mathfrak{u}$?

3) What is the value of $\kappa$ in the [Goldstern-Shelah model](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0168007290900638?via%3Dihub) of $\mathfrak{r}<\mathfrak{u}$?

Comment: I only saw this further development on my question today - thanks for your well-formulated exposition!