# Choosing *two* representatives

Tags: set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Although [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/275633/existence-of-a-diagonal-set-in-certain-set-systems) got an accepted answer, I still feel there are more questions to ask in this direction.

> Suppose that to every $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ there corresponds a subset $A_\alpha\subseteq\mathbb R$ with $|A_\alpha|=\mathfrak c$. Does there always exist a set $D\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $D\cap A_\alpha\ne\varnothing$ and $A_\alpha\nsubseteq D$ for each $\alpha\in\mathbb R$? Equivalently, does there always exist a choice function $f\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(\alpha)\in A_\alpha\nsubseteq\cup_{\alpha\in\mathbb R}\{f(\alpha)\}$ for each $\alpha\in\mathbb R$? Equivalently, do there always exist *two* choice functions $f,g\colon\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that $f(\alpha),g(\alpha)\in A_\alpha$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, while $\{f(\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in\mathbb R}$ and $\{g(\alpha)\}_{\alpha\in\mathbb R}$ are disjoint?

As [domotorp](https://mathoverflow.net/users/955/domotorp) obsrved in the comments, I am in fact asking whether any hypergraph with the vertex set, the number of edges, and the size of every edge all being of cardinality $\mathfrak c$, is $2$-colorable.

Comment: Is $\aleph=\mathfrak c $? You can build $D $ by transfinite recursion: Well-order the continuum in type $\mathfrak c $. At stage $\alpha $ you add a point of $A_\alpha $ to your set, and one to its complement. Yoy can always do this because at each stage fewer than $\mathfrak c $ points have been selected.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: Sounds much easier than what I expected. Would you convert this into an answer?

Comment: By the way, this is the standard way of building Bernstein sets: sets such that neither it nor its complement contains a perfect subset, the point being that there are only $\mathfrak c $ perfect sets.

Comment: Sure, I'll make this an answer once I'm home; typing on the phone is cumbersome.

Comment: Isn't this the same as asking whether the hypergraph whose edges are the $A_\alpha$ is $2$-colorable or not?

Comment: @Andrés: Excuses excuses excuses... ;)

Comment: @domotorp: absolutely. The positive answer below shows that any hypergraph on $\mathbb R$ is $2$-colorable provided that both the number of edges and the size of each edge are of the cardinality $\mathfrak c$. Nice interpretation!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume by $\aleph$ you [mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/444273/how-many-infinite-cardinals-are-smaller-than-aleph?noredirect=1#comment4871997_444273) $\mathfrak c$, the cardinality of the continuum. You can build $D$ by transfinite recursion: Well-order the continuum in type $\mathfrak c$. At stage $\alpha$ you add a point of $A_\alpha$ to your set, and one to its complement. You can always do this because at each stage fewer than $\mathfrak c$ many points have been selected.

The argument is standard, by the way, typically used to build Bernstein sets, that is, sets such that neither it nor its complement contains a perfect subset. The point is that there are precisely $\mathfrak c$ many perfect subsets of $\mathbb R$ (and any perfect set has size $\mathfrak c$).

Note that this particular case also shows that some amount of choice is needed to ensure the existence of $D$. This is because (modulo the consistency of an inaccessible cardinal) it is [consistent](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=265151) with $\mathsf{ZF}+\mathsf{DC}$ that every uncountable set of reals contains a perfect subset. ($\mathsf{DC}$ is the axiom of dependent choices, which suffices to develop classical analysis.)